# Sticky Footer Scrolling Horizontally with Vertical Scrolling Content in CSS

Tags: html, css

This seems to me currently like the quadrature of the circle, but nevertheless I try to ask this question here.

I need the following:

header - 100% width, fixed at top
  content - fixed width, vertically scrolling content
  footer - same width as content, fixed at bottom
scrollbar - scrolling horizontally simultaneously content and footer

I.e. there should be only one horizontal scrollbar at the bottom which scrolls content and footer simultaneously, but no scrollbar between content and footer. The vertical scrollbar should only affect the content.

(of course, the horizontal scrollbar should be auto, i.e. only appear if content/footer width is larger than the current viewport width)

The closest I have arrived at is the following HTML/CSS:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>scroll attempt</title>
</head>
<body style="overflow-x:hidden;height:100vh;margin:0;">
  <div style="height:100vh;display:flex;flex-direction:column;">
  <div style="width:100%;height:100px;background-color:red;">header</div>
  <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;height:100%;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;">
    <!--
      the following div should only have a vertical scrollbar,
      hence overflow-x:visible; - which is not respected
      when setting overflow-x:hidden; the horizontal scrollbar disappears
      but then the vertical scrollbar moves when scrolling horizontally
    -->
    <div style="flex:1;background-color:yellow;overflow-x:visible;overflow-y:auto;">
      <div style="width:1200px;height:800px;background-color:orange;">scrolling</div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:1200px;height:100px;background-color:green;">footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, with this HTML/CSS, an unwanted scrollbar appears on the div surrounding the inner content, which is located between content and footer, although overflow-x:visible; was set. When setting overflow-x:hidden; the scrollbar is gone, but then the vertical scrollbar is also scrolled by the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom instead of staying on the right of the page.

The behavior is mostly consistend in current IE/FF/Chrome versions. I also have a Javascipt version that fixes divs on window resize and on vertical scroll, but this flickers horribly in IE, which is why I'd prefer a pure CSS solution.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nftqjkyq/

Any ideas?

[edit: added more details about wanted behavior of the scrollbars]

Comment: just to illustrate how it should behave, here's a jsfiddle that works as wanted, but with Javascript (the question is how this can be achieved without Javascript): http://jsfiddle.net/3bhsswnv/

Answer (score 4):

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100px;background-color:green;">footer</div>
```

change the width of your footer to 100% if you want to remove the second scroll bar on your fiddle

Solved fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/nftqjkyq/1/

**EDIT** 
Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/nftqjkyq/4/

**EDIT**
With Sticky Footer that scrolls on overflow (This is impossible to scroll a fixed element using just css)

Here is a solution that could be closer to what you want.....maybe it can just give you the direction.

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nftqjkyq/10/

Comment: Maybe I did not make myself completely clear in my question - but here I try again: not the second scrollbar has to go, but the first one. And the footer has to scroll horizontally and simultaneously with the content (actually, content and footer each contain tabular data with equal metrics that have to match). Setting the footer's width to 100% actually fixes it instead of having it scroll together with the content.

Comment: Footer does not stick at the bottom of the page (this is clearly mentioned in my question).

Comment: basically similar to my jsfiddle - except that the vertical scrollbar is full height, whereas in mine it has the height of the scrolled section.

Comment: @RemigiusStalder but u clearly indicated that your fiddle has a bug where its showing 2 horizontal scroll bars...and u wanted solutions to take them out...sooo i did that.......so my fiddle is definitely different from yours in that respect......I could have sworn in your initial question you hilighted that you wanted to take out the second scroll bar